# Content is always null when I make a http put request

Tags: c#, .net, http, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have a web API that works. Now I'm writing integration tests for it but when I make the PUT request through the test, the `[FromBody]` data is always null. `RequestData` is a protobuf type that I've created.

This is the signature of the API method:

```
public async Task<Response> SomePutMethod(string id, [FromBody] RequestData data)
```

And in my test, I call it like this:

```
var request = new RequestData()
    
HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    
var putResult = await _client.PutAsync(uri + "?id=1", content);
```

I also tried `Jsonformatter.Default.Format` to convert the protobuf object to json string but that didn't work either.

Comment: Hi @an007, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 1):

Use the extension `PutAsJsonAsync()` from `System.Net.Http.Formatting.HttpClientExtensions`:

```
var data = new RequestData();
var resp = await _client.PutAsJsonAsync("https://www.example.com", data);
```

Or, use `SendAsync()`

```
using(var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "https://www.example.com/"))
{
    req.Headers.Accept.Add(new 
        MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    req.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), 
        Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    using(var resp = await _client.SendAsync(req))
    {
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        resp.Content.ReadAs...
    }
}
```

Comment: its still null. both ways

Comment: If the endpoint is being hit and the body is null, then your models don't match. There really is no other way to accomplish what you are trying to do. You said in your question that the endpoint works, just not when writing a test to consume it.

Comment: well why dont they match?? what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

> I make the PUT request through the test, the `[FromBody]` data is always null.

Please check your `RequestData` class and make sure you defined public properties, like below.

```
public class RequestData
{
    public string Content { get; set; }

    //...
    //other properties
```

If you defined them as Field(s) without `get` and `set` accessor, which might cause the issue.

Besides, please check if you assigned value to each property while you create an instance of `RequestData` class and populate `StringContent` with that `request` object.

```
var request = new RequestData();

request.Content = "hello world";
//...
```